# MVC 3.5 Windows Authentication on View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I am currently using built in Windows Authentication for my `MVC3` web app.

It works as expected but I can't seem to figure out how to hide certain links on a view based on what user is logged in. I found info on using `If (Roles.IsUserInRole)` but that dont work as I do not know that Windows roles if any we are using. I think we are using Groups instead of roles.

Thanks

Comment: I think roles = groups. However, I can't really give you an answer unless you can confirm how the user rights are set up. The solution depends on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Role = group membership, so you can use it like this:

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole("domain\\Administrators")) {
// do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the domain. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also use this solution:

```
  if (Roles.IsUserInRole("role","username")) { //should also work, worked for me in the MVC3
    // do something
    }
```